# On $\delta_{0}$-continuity sets in the class of finite dimensional sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S=C[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{S}$ be the Borel algebra given the sup metric. Furthermore consider the class of so called "finite dimensional sets" in $\mathcal{S}$ defined by

$\pi_{\{t_{I}\}_{0}^{n}}f=(f(t_{1}), \ldots,f(t_{n}))$ is the projection into $R^k$. Call a set a finite dimensional set in $C[0,1]$ if it is the inverse image of some Borel set in $R^k$ under this map.

Consider the function

$z_{n}(t)=nt\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(t) +(2-nt)\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]}(t) \in C[0,1]$

which converges pointwise but not uniformly to $0$.

I try to understand why the class of finite dimensional sets is not convergence determining by considering the measures $\delta_{z_{n}}$ and $\delta_{0}$ on $\mathcal{S}$.

A family of subsets is converging determining if it is sufficient to have that $P_{n}A \rightarrow PA$ for all $P$-continuity sets of that class to obtain weak convergence of the measures $P_{n}$ to $P$

As $z_{n}$ does not convergence uniformly to $0$ it is clear that $\delta _{z_{n}}$ don't converge weakly to $\delta _{0}$.

What I don't see is why this proves the finite dimensional sets are not converging determining. Since I don't understand how one should think about the $\delta _{0}$-continuity sets.

Why is the condition

$\delta _{z_{n}}A \rightarrow \delta _{0}A$ for all $\delta _{0}$-continuity sets $A$ in the class of finite dimensional sets satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds not only for finite-dimensional $\delta_0$-continuity sets, but even for all finite-dimensional sets. Those are of the form 
$$
A = \{f(t_1)\in B_1,\dots, f(t_k)\in B_k\}
$$
for some distinct $t_1,\dots,t_k\in[0,1]$ and measurable $B_1,\dots,B_k\subset \mathbb{R}$.

For all $n$ large enough we have $(0,2/n)\cap\{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k\} = \varnothing$. Then $$\delta_0(A) = \delta_{z_n}(A) = \mathbb{1}_{0\in B_i\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,k}.$$